# Duda con codeigneter

Tags: php

Tengo dos tablas 'clientes' y 'famClientes' conectadas por 'clientes_idclientes'

Cuando se agrega un cliente, este cliente puede iniciar una session donde aparecen sus datos (hasta ahí no tengo problema ya crea la sesión y muestra datos) el problema que tengo es que tengo que mostrar toda la información de famClientes por ejemplo: usuario1(con id '3') tiene en famClientes a 2 personas.

Controlador:

```
public function logueado() {
       if($this->session->userdata('logueado')){
         $data = array();
         $data['familiares'] = $this->usuario_model->familiares();
         $data['usuario'] = $this->session->userdata('usuario');
         $this->load->view('admin/inicio', $data);
         $this->usuario_model->familiares();
      }else{
         redirect('login');
      }
   }
```

Modelo

```
    function cliente($idclientes) {
      $consulta = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idclientes='.$id);

      return $consulta->row();
   }



Public function familiares() {
      $consulta = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM famClientes where clientes_idclientes=14');
      return $consulta->row();
   }
```

Lo de clientes_idclientes=14 lo puse asi para hacer la prueba, pero solo me muestra 1, necesito que me muestre todos los de ese id

Comment: Intenta haciendo return $consulta->result(); que te retorna todos los valores de tu query, en vez de return $consulta->row(); que solo te retorna una sola fila

Comment: Hola juan, muchas gracias. Fue lo que hice pero me aparece error:

MESSAGE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT

Comment: En donde te sale el error, en el controlador o en el modelo?

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo resolvi era un problema con el foreach y si me sirvio el result(); saludos juan pinzón :D

Comment: Si encuentras la solución para tu propio problema, no dudas de responder a ti mismo con la solución. Puede ayudar a otros que encuentran la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos y espero que te sirva esto ...

modelo

```
// row = lo usas por que es 1 o nada
function cliente($idclientes) {
      $consulta = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE idclientes='.$idclientes);
      return $consulta->row();
}

// result = respuesta puede ser 1 o mas
Public function familiares($idclientes){
      $consulta = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM famClientes where clientes_idclientes'.$idclientes);
      return $consulta->result();
}
```